# When does the MessageChannel.send method return?

Tags: java, sftp, spring-integration

I'm trying to generate a file in a local folder, then send it over SFTP to a remote server and finally delete the 'temporary' file created. Almost all works fine.

ISSUE:
When I try to delete the file, using File.delete (or Files.delete), it won't do it. Reason: file is used by another process. Note that there is no other process (other than the one sending it over sftp) which is using the file.

Code to process the file below:

```
List<Order> orders = orderRepository.findAll();
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(tempFile)) {
    contentCreator.generateContent(orders, fileWriter);
    LOGGER.debug("Handover file written successfully " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot write in the temp folder. Handover failed.", e);
}

final Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(tempFile).build();
if (sftpChannel.send(message)) { //sftpChannel comes autowired by Spring IoC
    doLogicInCaseOfSuccess(); //I set some DB records after the file was sent successfully over sftp.
    tempFile.delete(0);
}
```

And here is the configuration:

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="apstChannel"/>

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
                                   session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                   channel="apstChannel"
                                   charset="UTF-8"
                                   remote-directory="${dropFolder}"
                                   />
```

What I don't understand is how come the file is still in use, even though the `MessageChannel.send` method returned true (thus, transfer was successful)?

Since I couldn't find any documentation, I now am not convinced that the method will return true when the file was queued to be sent over sftp, or after it was actually sent. Do you know when the `send` method returns?

Also, if you know of other ways how I could delete that file, that would be great.

Comment: Looks like it isn't an issue of SFTP process. How do you keep that `tempFile` before sending to SFTP? Maybe have you forgotten to close the file stream?

Comment: I've added the code that writes the file. The stream is closed when existing the try-catch block (using java 7).

Comment: Because Spring Integration is based on message queues, it seems impossible to handle anything synchronous and get feedback from the job. Though, I'm quite beginner at Spring Integration, I probably am missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

According to its Javadoc it returns true if the message has been successfully sent, which implies that it can't return until the send is complete, in the success case. It can return immediately in the failure case of course.

It should throw an exception in the failure case of course, rather than just returning false. Poor design.

Comment: Yes, an exception would have been better here. It actually can throw a RuntimeException if anything went wrong, though a more specific one would have been nice. But it is still not clear what 'sent' means. Is it sent to the messaging queue, or sent to the remote server (thus when message was processed)? I'm currently looking at doing this with JSch directly as Spring Integration seems too complex for a fairly simple task like this.